# MySQL character set and collation

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

Ok, quick question regarding charset/collation.

If I have a database where the collation_database=latin1_swedish_ci but all the tables and columns have been created using utf8 will it differ from a database that has collation_database=utf8_general_ci with the same tables/columns? (I realise that creating new tables will pick up latin1 unless specified).

Am I right in thinking that collation_database (and character_set_database) are only defaults and they can just be overridden on table creation?

Cheers,
Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are only defaults. The columns are the things that have an encoding in MySQL. If you do not specify an encoding for a column, the next higher default applies (table encoding, database encoding, server encoding). That's all.